# Is this definition of a polynomial adequate? If not, how do I fix it?

Tags: polynomials

A function $p$ is a polynomial with coefficients in **F** if $p$: **F** $ \to$ **F** as $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2 + ··· + a_mz^m$ for some $a_0,\ldots,a_m$ and all $z \in$ **F**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your definition of polynomial doesn't agree with what usually people want to model.

Note that taking $\mathbb F=\{0,1\}$, according to your definition, setting $p(x)=x^2+1$ and $q(x)=x+1$, for all $x\in \{0,1\}$, one has $p=q$. But usually it is wished that $p\neq q$.

What you've defined is a [polynomial function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#Polynomial_functions).

The operator that takes polynomials to its polynomial functions isn't injective in general (see example above), therefore you can't equate polynomial function with polynomial.

But it works sometimes, namely in fields of characteristic $0$.

Comment: It works for all infinite fields even if they don't hace characteristic 0.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena Thank you for your comment. Please keep it there for future reference.

Comment: Also for infinite integral domains.