# Is this a fruitful enrichment of $R[X]$?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Then polynomial ring $R\left[X\right]$ can be looked
at as an $R$-algebra free over a singleton. If $S$ is another $R$-algebra
then for any element $s\in S$ there is a unique homomorphims $\phi:R\left[X\right]\rightarrow S$
determined by $X\mapsto s$.

So there is a one-to-one correspondence
between $\mathbf{Hom}\left(R\left[X\right],S\right)$ and $S$ and
the structure on $S$ as $R$-algebra can be transferred to $\mathbf{Hom}\left(R\left[X\right],S\right)$.

In special case $S=R\left[X\right]$ on $\mathbf{End}\left(R\left[x\right]\right)$
there is also a structure induced by composition of endomorphisms.
Now we can go the other way: this structure can be transferred to
$R\left[X\right]$.

> My question: Will this enrich $R\left[X\right]$, and are there examples of practicizing this?

Working with abelian groups a likewise procedure turns abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$
into ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: See the paragraph above "a quick remark" at http://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/operations-and-lawvere-theories/.

Comment: The new structure is the composition of polynomials. Of course this operation has been studied. But many problems are quite hard as compared to multiplication or addition (see for example the Jacobian conjecture).

Comment: If you are interested in extra structures on algebras, you might be interested in the theory of "plethories" see for example http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biring and http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/plethory