# Polynomials (expressions) vs polynomial functions

Tags: polynomials

I was reading the two posts in the references to understand the distinction between polynomials and polynomial functions, yet I felt that I couldn't find the conclusion... So let me ask here.

Is it correct to rephrase the above comparison as polynomial `expressions` and polynomial functions as a `polynomial` is an expression of relations of variables and a `polynomial function` actually allows us to evaluate it on some value in a field of domain.

For instance, from [@GitGud](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/813860/733176), suppose two polynomial functions $p(x) = x^2 + 1$ and $q(x) = x+1$ on $\mathbb{F} = \{ 0, 1 \}$, then $p(x) = q(x)$ as $p(x=0) = q(x = 0)$ or $p(x=1) = q(x = 1)$. But as expressions, $p \neq q$.

#### References

- [Polynomials vs polynomial functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815440/polynomials-vs-polynomial-functions)
- [Is this definition of a polynomial adequate? If not, how do I fix it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813854/is-this-definition-of-a-polynomial-adequate-if-not-how-do-i-fix-it/813860#813860)